# Jquery - Popupwindow Not Working on FIrst Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use a `popupwindow` function. The problem is, it works only on the second click and so on. If I refresh the page, it will not work on first click. Why does it happen? Below are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function popup(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".popupwindow").popupwindow();
    }

    $('.popupwindow').on("click", popup);
});
```

Link that use the function:

```
<a href="mylink.php" class="popupwindow">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Could you please make sure if there aren't any console errors in your browser?

Comment: I check on the console, there is no error. If I use only `$(".popupwindow").popupwindow();`, it works fine but If I made it in a function like above, the problem will occur.

Comment: did you try remove e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: @YiğitYüksel If I remove the `e.preventDefault();`, it will open on a new tab. Then, on the second click, it open on a new window which is the popupwindow function.

Comment: Try keeping an alert within your function to make sure your function is been called everytime..

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will try to look for it. At the moment, I will not use the function popup().